# Python3 and Pyglet - help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I am a newbie of Python and Pyglet. I just installed Pyglet on my Linux and Window7. I run a very simple test file on my Linux, I got errors

(On linux: Python 3.5.2 Pyglet 1.2.4)

The following is the test file-tests.py:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
pyglet.app.run()
```

I got the following errors when I run it on my Linux:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/init.py", line 351, in getattr return getattr(self._module, name)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Window'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 6, in <module> window = pyglet.window.Window() File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/init.py", line 357, in getattr import(import_name)

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/init.py", line 1816, in <module> gl._create_shadow_window()

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/init.py", line 205, in _create_shadow_window _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/init.py", line 163, in init super(XlibWindow, self).init(args, *kwargs)

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/init.py", line 558, in init self._create()

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/init.py", line 353, in _create self.set_caption(self._caption)

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/init.py", line 513, in set_caption self._set_text_property('_NET_WM_NAME', caption)

File "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/init.py", line 783, in _set_text_property raise XlibException('Could not create UTF8 text property')

pyglet.window.xlib.XlibException: Could not create UTF8 text property*
```

This test file works ok on my Win7

(On Window7: Python 3.6.0 Pyglet 1.2.4)

Please help if you know why. Thanks.

Comment: Were there any error messages when you installed `pyglet`?  This has the markings of a failed install.

Comment: I used: pip3 install pyglet : I got: "Installing collected packages: pyglet
Successfully installed pyglet-1.2.4"

Comment: @anch0ret `sudo pip install pyglet`

Comment: @Torxed I tried sudo pip3 install pyglet I got "Collecting pyglet
  Downloading pyglet-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (964kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 972kB 28kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyglet
Successfully installed pyglet-1.2.4". Then I tried: sudo python3 test.py, and I got the almost same errors, only difference is the directory:  instead of "/home/work/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/", this time is "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyglet"

Comment: Have you installed `mesa` and other graphical dependencies? It looks like you're running a non-standard locale, what's in your `/etc/locale.conf` (The uncommented lines)

Comment: @Torxed "non-standard locale" which you mentioned solved my problem. Thank you very much. By the way, How can I vote for you?

Comment: @anch0ret I made a answer regarding the whole thing. If it's not fully accurate let me know :)

Comment: Reproduces on Ubuntu 20.04 as well. https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/520.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out from the comments above, it looked like the installation output printed some odd symbols. That and the fact that pyglet had problem loading UTF-8 context lead me to believe that there were no UTF-8 support generated in the OS.

Usually, you can uncomment `en_US.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.conf` and run `locale-gen` and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in your terminal

1. write `LANG=en_US`
2. Run your python code from the terminal

another solution by placing it before everything of your code

```
import os
os.environ['LANG']='en_US'
```

Comment: make it:  
import os
os.environ['LANG']='en_US.UTF-8'

Comment: Unlike setting the environment variable from outside the program, changing the environment as the first thing in the program itself, does not seem to change the issue, at least in my setup with python 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

1. edit your `/etc/default/locale`, and try to feed all locale critiria as the same:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

1. Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` to set your own language. Make sure to mark `en_US.UTF-8` selection.
2. `sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8`
3. Reboot